How does this LM317 current boost circuit work?
Can someone please explain how this circuit works, as well as explaining the roles of each component in the circuit?

What is the effect of the 500ohm resistor and the resistor on the right side of the 1N4002 diode?
Why is the load installed at Vout so 22ohm-resistor knows how to adjust 2N2905?

Welcome. Could you please put the details of where you got this circuit from?

i don't know at all, my teacher gave me this circuit. I searched it on google and only knew that it's a " High-Current Adjustable Regulator Circuit" from Texas Instruments that allows higher current at Vout than the LM317 can provide.

Sounds like homework, but I’ll gives some hints:  refer to the TI/national Semiconductor datasheet that explains the basic circuit configuration for the LM317. As for the extra two transistors, as more load is applied, more voltage is dropped across the 22R resistor which in turn causes the 2N2905 to conductor more which, in turn, causes the TIP73 to conduct more. Since your teacher gave you this task, you should have enough basic knowledge to explain in more detail.

See also  Sziklai pair.

@Kartman I'm fond of giving hints / leading questions in response to homework questions -- if this comment were an answer, I would upvote it :)

I still have a few questions:
1/ What is the effect of the 500ohm resistor and the resistor on the right side of the 1N4002 diode ?
2/ Why is the load installed at Vout so 22ohm-resistor knows how to adjust 2N2905

What is the effect of the 500ohm resistor it's there to keep the TIP73 off until some level of loading is reached. If 2N2905 conducts enough (i.e. at least 1.1 mA, presumably) then the TIP73 will start conducting. Without the 500R resistor, the base-emitter voltage of the TIP73 will keep increasing with the loading so it may turn on below the intended loading level.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please update your image to include component identifiers. It is much easier to present an explanation using identifiers rather than values, eg: "Q1" rather than "PNP 2N2905".

Thank you for your explanation, Rohat. I also updated my image as you said, Fabio

When you figure this out, you might want to 1. Calculate or simulate power dissipation of the transistors, the 22Ω resistor and the LM317 in a situation where this circuit might be used (say24V in and 12V at 10A out). 2. Figure out what likely happens if the output is shorted (the LM317 itself has both thermal and over-current protection).

Here is the behavior of this circuit.
I use TIP33 not having TIP71 in my database (should use 2N3055)
.
Made with microcap v12.
Just testing the change of resistor (R11) in the base of Q1.


The main component that I see in this circuit diagram is LM317 which is an adjustable voltage regulator. This means this is mainly a voltage regulator circuit.
In the left, 22 ohm and 5 kohm resistors are acting as voltage dividers for the input voltage Vi. (I leave that calculation to you, it is very easy.)
The 2N2905 (PNP transistor) is acting as a current amplifier for the LM317. It senses the output current and, if the current demand increases, it helps the LM317 by providing additional current to the load.
The TIP73 (NPN transistor) works alongside the 2N2905 to further increase the current capacity.
The TIP73 takes over the majority of the load current once the demand surpasses a certain threshold, protecting the LM317 from overheating or damage.
Finally, the diode is used for protection and the capacitors are used for filtering out any high-frequency noise from the input voltage and stabilize the operation of the LM317, preventing oscillations in the output voltage.

How do the 22 Ω and 5 kΩ resistors constitute a voltage divider?

@Hearth. They don't. Naveed Ahmed is "uninformed", to put it kindly.
